# Categorize Similar items into separate objects from Array lists

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array of items that I get from API as a response body.

```
data = [{id: 1, category: "kitchen", name: "noodles"},
        {id: 2, category: "general", name: "Wi-Fi"},
        {id: 3, category: "sports", name: "Football"},]
```

I want to iterate over the arrays, and get the data like :

```
var categorized = {
 kitchen: [{id: 1, category: "kitchen", name: "noodles"}],
 general : [{id: 2, category: "general", name: "Wi-Fi"}],
 sports : [{id: 3, category: "sports", name: "Football"}]
};
```

Is there any lodash methods, or any ES6 shortcuts for this ?

Comment: I believe `categorized` is an object?

Comment: @SandeepNayak, Array makes no sense there :D

Comment: @ShankarRegmi: reason being I didnt see any {}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In answer to your question 'is there a lodash method?'  Yes: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy.  For your specific example:

```
const categorized = _.groupBy(data, 'category');
```

Edit: You could roll your own groupBy type function with ES6 as in another example.  But if you are using lodash anyway this is a whole lot cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

I used `array.reduce` to get the structure

```js
var data = [{
  id: 1,
  category: "kitchen",
  name: "noodles"
}, {
  id: 2,
  category: "general",
  name: "Wi-Fi"
}, {
  id: 3,
  category: "sports",
  name: "Football"
}]


var newData = data.reduce(function(obj, v, i) {

  obj[v.category] = obj[v.category] || [];
  obj[v.category].push(v);
  return obj;

}, {});
console.log(newData);
```

**In ES6 you could so using:**

```
   var newData = data.reduce((obj, v, i)=> {

      obj[v.category] = obj[v.category] || [];
      obj[v.category].push(v);
      return obj;

    }, {});
    console.log(newData);
```